# How can I visualize a 300x300 grid of home values over time with python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to show how land values in a 300 x 300 plot area are increasing over time through a color visualization over time. Each cell is a unique home (whose value changes over time) and if a home gets more expensive, it should turn a darker color. I was going to try to use tkinter but I couldn't change the cell sizes. So I have two questions: should I use some other sort of data visualization tool to help me do this or is there a way to make the default cells in tkinter smaller?

```
window = Tk()

for i in range(0,301):

    for j in range(0,301):

        Label(window, width="1", height="1", bg="green").grid(row=j, column=i)

mainloop()
```

Comment: If your cells are in a grid why not use [`plt.pcolormesh`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh.html) and animate that?

Comment: A 300x300 grid of colours sounds like an image to me - a heatmap. Maybe consider using a **PIL** `Image`.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it would be better to use a Canvas with rectangles instead of labels on a grid. If you keep the values of the rectangle objects in a list, you can directly manipulate them from any other function in order to change the colors according to whatever program you write around this grid.

The following example uses a very simplified set-up of your problem with only a 2x2-grid and three points in time. You can scale this approach to make it suitable for 300x300 and also upgrade the `color()` function to display actual sensible colors on your grid.

```
from tkinter import *

grid = [[1,1,1],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[3,2,1]] ## Just 4 cells with 3 time points

def setup(window,grid):
    window.c = Canvas(window,width=80,height=80,bg="#ffffff")
    window.c.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=2)
    window.data = grid
    window.box = []
    for x in range(2):
        for y in range(2):
            col = color(window.data[x+2*y][0])
            b = window.c.create_rectangle(x*40,y*40,x*40+40,y*40+40,fill=col)
            window.box.append(b)

    Button(window,text="+",command=next_time).grid(row=1,column=1)
    Button(window,text="-",command=prev_time).grid(row=1,column=0)
    window.current = StringVar()
    window.current.set("Time = 0")
    window.currentint = 0
    Label(window,textvariable=window.current).grid(row=2,column=0,columnspan=2)
                                                   

def color(idx):
    return ['#ff0000','#ffff00','#00ff00','#0000ff'][idx]

def next_time():
    if w.currentint < 2:
        w.currentint += 1
        for i in range(len(w.box)):
            w.c.itemconfigure(i,fill=color(w.data[i][w.currentint]))
            w.current.set(f"Time = {w.currentint}")
    else:
        print("ERROR: You are already at the last point")

def prev_time():
    if w.currentint > 0:
        w.currentint -= 1
        for i in range(len(w.box)):
            w.c.itemconfigure(i,fill=color(w.data[i][w.currentint]))
            w.current.set(f"Time = {w.currentint}")
    else:
        print("ERROR: You are at the first point")


w = Tk()
setup(w,grid)
w.mainloop()
```

This little program uses a `setup()` function to prepare the tkinter widget. It's just a window with a canvas, two buttons, and a label. It also adds four attributes to the widget:

- `.data` holds the information of the original 2x2-array of lists of values for each point in time. This is the data which is being visualized. You would have a list of length 90000 containing lists of the length of your observation.
- `.box` holds the indices of all the rectangles in the box. It directly links each element of the data list to the visualization.
- `.current` contains a string indicating the current position in the data.
- `.currentint` contains the current list index in time as an integer.

The buttons call two functions that increase or decrease the current point in time. At the same time, they update the fill color of all rectangles to take the color corresponding to this point in time.

And that's basically it. Now you can scale it to your larger data.

(P.S: Although it would be possible to use a scrollbar instead of two buttons, I would advise against it for a 300x300 grid. The time required to update it would lead to considerable lags.)